# How can i assign and maintain values to session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms, session

I am using web browser control inside my application window application. is their any possibility to set or change session values through my application? is it possible to create or destroy session from windows application?

in web application i can create session using :

```
 session("user")="loginUSer"
```

is their any similar process available in vb.net application?

Comment: If you are trying to figure out the equivlant of session variables in WinForms, then look at one of the answers below. If you are trying to modify a session variable that's contained in a webbrowser control, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579997/fill-a-session-variable-from-windows-app-using-web-browser-control

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of Session in windows forms. You can create a static class. And then assigned a value to its variable when you want to log in.

```
Public static class login
{
  public static string userId {get; set;}
}

login.userId = txtuserID.Text;
```

and set to null or empty string during log out.

U can set and remove the session variables in C#.net like

```
Session["UserID"] = UserID;
Session.Remove("UserID"); or  Session["UserID"] = null;
```

And in VB.Net

```
Session("UserID") = UserID
Session.Remove("UserID") or Session("UserID") = Nothing
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `login.userId = txtuserID.Text;` - if he's accessing it outside of the `login` class ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for "Session state" in a Windows application - you can store as much state in memory as you need. You can't *directly* set or remove session state values of a web application from your Windows app, but if you have access to the code for both, you could be crafty and have a 'hidden' page that you pass values to in the querystring to set or remove session state, i.e. 'http://mysite/sessionpage?variable=value'. Does this make sense ?